# Iterate over directories created in a specific month in Bash

Tags: bash, loops

I am trying to iterate over directories which were created in a specific month. For e.g. in the below screenshot (which shows the set of directories in my current working directory that I want to iterate on), I only want to iterate over directories created in 'Jul' (essentially the last 5 directories)

[image]

I was trying something along the lines of below code but it iterates over all the elements like date, day, time etc. -

```
for dir in `ls -l <dir> | grep 'Jul'`
do
    dir=${dir%*/}
    echo ${dir##*/}
done
```

Comment: What is your screen shot showing?  The create date (last modified date) followed by the directory name?

Comment: Most file systems do not store the information when a file or directory was created.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Do it using `stat` command

Answer (score 0):

Onliner should do the trick:

```
for dir in `ls -l <dir> | grep Jul | awk '{ print $9}'`; do echo $dir;done
```